# If raw data is made available for non-commercial use, am I allowed to seek profit from the use of statistics I gather using the data?

Tags: california, terms-of-service

The CHP has a traffic database filled with raw data that is for "personal, non-commercial use". Here's the database: [database](http://iswitrs.chp.ca.gov/Reports/jsp/RawData.jsp)

What I want to do is use this data to compile some statistics, the use of which I intend to profit from. Is this legal under the TOS & relevant law?

Comment: I'm somewhat skeptical that CHP has the right to restrict the data to non-commercial use, despite whatever terms they list, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant [definitions](http://www.bing.com/search?FORM=UWDFNT&PC=U302&q=commercial%20definition&src=IE-TopResult&conversationid=) of **commercial** are:

> 1. concerned with or engaged in commerce: 
>      "*a commercial agreement*"
> 2. making or intended to make a profit: 
>      "*commercial products*"

So **non-commercial** means neither of those things. If you intend to make a profit then you actions are **commercial** and a breach of the ToS and therefore against the law.